# How to handle multiple ajax request error using Deferred?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble handling multiple jquery ajax call, there are timeout error, but how do I know which request error this is?

```
$.when(ajaxDeferred1, ajaxDeferred2)
  .done(function(result1, result2) {})
  .fail(function(response, statusText) {
  // how do I know which(ajaxDeferred1 or ajaxDeferred2) ajax call error this is?
});
```

**ajaxDeferred1**

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: xxx,
  timeout: 5000,
});
```

I know I can handle error by putting '.fail()' on each request, but is there any way handle error above way?

Going further, can I handle like this?

```
$.when(ajaxDeferred1, ajaxDeferred2)
  .done(function(result1, result2) {})
  .fail(function(errorForRequest1, errorForRequest2) {
  // handle error
});
```

**EDIT:**

I think I need to make my question more clear. In the above example:

```
$.when(ajaxDeferred1, ajaxDeferred2)
  .done(function(result1, result2) {})
  .fail(function(errorForRequest1, errorForRequest2) {
  // if all request has done, but one or more request has got error, return the error here then! 
  // So I can handle which part UI should show and which UI part I should hide due to the error!
});
```

I want to get 'done' result when all is done without error, and get 'error' when all is **done** but one or more request has encountered problem and return them all together into '.fail()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @Miguel Mota's answer. But as an alternative, you are going to get your deferred object back if it fails. So you can add some data to it:

```
var dfd1 = jQuery.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'some request that fails first',
    timeout: 1
});

dfd1.id = 1;

var dfd2 = jQuery.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'some request that fails second',
    timeout: 1000
});

dfd2.id = 2;

jQuery.when(dfd1, dfd2)
    .done(function () { })
    .fail(function (request) {
        // id: 1
        console.log('id: ' + request.id);
    });
```

Comment: Hi this is more closer to my intension. The only problem is 'fail()' will block other ajax requests to continue, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.always()` and within it iterate over each promise and check whether it resolved or failed.

```
var promises = [ajaxDeferred1, ajaxDeferred2]

$.when.apply($, promises)
  .always(function() {
    $.each(promises, function(i) {
      this.done(function(result) {
        console.log('promise', i, 'resolved');
      }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log('promise', i, 'failed');
      });
    });
  });
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pr45eov1/3/**

Answer (score 1):

##### Complete error handling using $.when with multiple requests

```js
var request1 = $.ajax({
    url: '...',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        // data
    }
});

var request2 = $.ajax({
    url: '...',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        // data
    }
});

$.when(request1, request2)
.done(
    function(response1, response2) {

        // success response from both

        var jsonMvtoData = response1[0];
        var resp1statusCode = response1[2].status;

        var jsonTipoOperacion = response2[0];
        var resp2statusCode = response2[2].status;

})
.fail(function(){

    // One or both requests failed

    [request1, request2].forEach(function(req) {
        req.fail(function(jqXHR) {

           // if both request fails, this will execute twice
           // you can do what u want with the json responses
           // for example store all of them in an array
                
            if (jqXHR.responseText) {
                try {
                    // Parsed JSON from failed request
                    var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                  console.error("JSON from failed request:", jqXHR.responseJSON);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error("Failed to parse JSON:", e);
                }
            }

        });
    });
});
```